# Android app Text-to-Speech voice download notification for users

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-internet

I have coded my Android app with "Text-to-Speech", voice "English-UK",

```
  lg.setLanguage(Locale.UK)
```

So, when I install it's apk in a new mobile for testing, it starts downloading voice "English-UK", as shown below,

[image]

But, if the Internet isn't working, while accessing app for the first time, then the app's function to read aloud text won't work.

But, after it gets installed, the app works fine and their is no need to install the same language again.

What should I do in this case, so that users don't feel confused after downloading my app. How will they  understand that the app needs "Voice-UK"? Should I notify them, if yes, then how,

```
   Retry ?
   Internet isn't working ?
   A dialog box showing install English-UK?
```

Comment: I guess you should display a dialog with why it is downloading voice data!

Comment: If "Text to Speech" is you core requirement than you should use AlertDialog to notify user other wise just download it when there is internet

Comment: @AndiGeeky And the dialog shouldn't be visible next time, if the user downloaded it, right?

Comment: @Aman Chawla Yes :)